# jQuery slow squishes table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to hide and show rows in a table.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nbf75/5/

Notice that when you click a question, the answer slides in but it squishes the question.
It doesn't do that if you set no animation, but I want an animation (not necessarily the preset slow animation, but any animation squishes it.)

So how do I get the animations to not squish the question?

**Edit:** This happens in Chrome but not Firefox, haven't tested in any other browsers yet

Comment: It doesn't look like your fiddle has a slide animation set. Did you paste the right URL?

Comment: Yeah, I just followed the one in my post and it's the right one. Click on a red question

Comment: Appears to be working OK in firefox 8.0.

Comment: I'll tell you if it works for my in Firefox or not after I download firefox

Comment: Yes, it does work fine in Firefox, but it doesn't work at all in Chrome, and it needs to be Chrome compatible

Comment: I figured it out and answered my own question =p I would like to know how to animate the questions though so they slide when I hide or show an answer instead of teleport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an artifact of how the rendering engine handles table cells. You can work around it by wrapping the answer (inside the `td`) in a `div`, and operating directly on that `div`. The `td` will follow suit (since it's automatically sized) and the effect is the same across all browsers.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Nbf75/11/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Just use fadeOut and fadeIn instead of show and hide. You will achieve the desired affect without the squishing.

Example:

```
$('table tr td.question').toggle(function() {
    $($(this).parent('tr').next('tr').children('.answer')).fadeOut('slow');
}, function() {
    $($(this).parent('tr').next().children('.answer')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nbf75/10/

Comment: Why does this work though? The behavior with hide/show is frankly bizarre. It would be nice to know what is going on.